# (When) Will m2crypto be ported to Python3?

Tags: m2crypto

Is there a port underway of m2crypto to Python3? I'm going to be starting a new toy project that needs cross-platform/cross-language crypto, and m2crypto looks like the way to go, but I'd rather work with Py3, to avoid having to explicitly convert to UTF8 everywhere.

Is there any chance that a port of this library is underway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A person started working on this and produced a partial patch which is available in https://bugzilla.osafoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12853. It would need someone who has need for Python 3.0 to finish it up.

Comment: After all shuffling back and forth, changing maintainers of the project, we are now at https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/merge_requests/65 with the merge request for Python 3 support.

Answer (score 3):

Code is at https://gitorious.org/chandler/m2crypto (branch python3), but it has not been finished yet (tests still fail). If somebody is willing to help with the finishing it, it would be awesome and the endless amount of positive karma waits for you from $DEITY.