# m2crypto migration to Python3.2

Tags: python-3.x, m2crypto

I am migrating a python 2 project to python3.2. I am stuck on options for M2Crypto. On the forums I only found that M2Crypto still does not support Python3 and a lot of folks have moved to pycrypto.

Any alternatives that you guys suggest ? Or should I look at pycrypto.

Thx

Comment: What's the status on M2Crypto?

Comment: Any help with https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/merge_requests/65 is more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue opened on the git of M2Crypto.
It seems to be under development since a year.

[(When) Will m2crypto be ported to Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466252/when-will-m2crypto-be-ported-to-python3)

There is a python3 branch that you can try out.
But I guess, there is no warranty that it will work.
https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/tree/python3